# Скачать файл POST запросом в Ext JS

Tags: post, extjs, filestream

Есть форма с ID, логином и паролем на Ext JS.
Хочу сделать чтоб прилетали на сервер эти поля и в случае доступа возвращался файл для скачивания.
Загвоздка в том, что не могу понять как сделать так, чтоб при отправке POST запроса и возврата файла, Ext JS показывал бы диалог с сохранением файла.  Сейчас в submit прилетает сырые байты файла.

Comment: Присылайте либо url, либо используйте Blob контейнер.

Comment: Можно подробнее про Blob контейнер?

Comment: Посмотрите например https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159179/how-to-convert-blob-to-file-in-javascript